# How can I make table with ReactTable that contains sub tables

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have React-Table component, and I need to insert into it data that contains sub-data (sub table).

I need to add an expander to the table that when we click on it, the parent row will expand and show the children

```
[{
  instrument: 'bitcoin',
  tradeAmount: '4000',
  children: [
      {
         instrument: 'bitcoin',
         tradeAmount: '1000'
      },
      {
         instrument: 'bitcoin',
         tradeAmount: '3000'
      }
    ]
 },
 {
  instrument: 'ethereum',
  tradeAmount: '6500'
 }
]
```

I tried to add to the `<ReactTable />` component 'pivotBy' attribute, and also to use  SubComponent attribute, but they do not help me.
someone know how to do it?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/archives/v6-examples/react-table-pivoting-sub-components

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: Above link is expired, This is latest  https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/sub-components